# How do I only enable cookies if the user logs in?

Tags: python, cookies, flask

I have a Flask app that runs on https behind nginx. The app also uses flask-login to log users in.

I have set my app.secret_key and have 3 views:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = Login()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # log the user in...
        ......
        return redirect(request.args.get('next') or '/')
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)

@login_required
@app.route('/logged_in')
def logged_in():
    return render_template('logged_in.html')
```

The vast, vast majority of my users do not log in (and don't have a user account) and some are complaining that we are setting cookies on them. I can confirm this behavior in my browser (Firefox) when I delete the cookie, visit "https://www.example.com" and see that the cookie gets reset.

How do I change the behavior so that the cookie only gets reset if the user logs in?